# Archiving forums on time basis in drupal 7

Tags: nodes

I am using advance forum on drupal 7. I want to add following functionality to it:

**Archiving:**

I could define forum posts older than 6 months or so should be automatically be archived and visible only to admin.

Any module or pointers to achieve same highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module.

Create a rule to set the node status to "unpublished" when the node is older than 6 months and make it execute every time the cron runs.

Also, make sure you allow only the admin to see the unpublished content

Comment: i don't want to unpublish them, i want to have a different state- "archive" which will not be visible in search and will only be read-only by some user-roles on site.